# C++ : Visual Studio compiler crash with partial template specialization on method ptr parameter

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

I have the following code that build fine with GCC but not with VS2010 or 2013 :

The header file:

```
#pragma once

#include <type_traits>

namespace utilities {

template<typename ValueType, typename ObjectType, ValueType (ObjectType::*BindingMethod)(), typename = void>
class Property
{
public:
    Property(ObjectType& object) : mObject(object)
    {
        mDirty = true;
    }

    operator const ValueType&() const
    {
        if (mDirty)
        {
            mObject.BindingMethod();
            mDirty = false;
        }
        return mValue;
    }
protected:
    ObjectType&         mObject;
    mutable bool        mDirty;
    ValueType           mValue;
};

template<typename ValueType, typename ObjectType, ValueType (ObjectType::*BindingMethod)()>
class Property<ValueType, ObjectType, BindingMethod, typename std::enable_if<BindingMethod==nullptr>::type>
{
public:
    Property()
    {
    }

    ValueType& operator=(const ValueType& value)
    {
        mValue = value;
        return mValue;
    }

    operator const ValueType&() const
    {
        return mValue;
    }
protected:
    ValueType           mValue;
};

class   A
{
public:
    A() : p2(*this)
    {

    }

    Property<int, A, nullptr>   p1;

    int    p2Binding()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    Property<int, A, &A::p2Binding>   p2;
};

void    Property_Tests()
{
    A   a;
    //a.p1 = 10;
    //int val = a.p1;
}

}
```

VS compiler crash when parsing the declaration of A::p1 member.
Our goal is to be able to have the same class name using the template specialization for the special case of Property without the binding method.

Is there a workaround to this compiler bug?

PS: We can't migrate to a more recent version of VS studio than the 2013 version because of tools and dependencies we are using.

Comment: Still produces an ICE in VS2015 Update 1.